# python: different result when using numba

Tags: python, numba

I have written the following program using python,one of which is accelerated by numba and the other is not.
The following is the code:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def lambert_jit(x):
    """
    inverse function: y = x*exp(x)
    parma: x>0
    """
    y=np.log(x)
    x1=1e-4
    x2=x
    while abs(x1-x2)>1e-8:
        x=(x1+x2)/2
        if (np.log(x1)+x1-y)*(np.log(x)+x-y)<=0:
            x2=x
        else:
            x1=x
    return x

def lambert_without_jit(x):
    """
    inverse function: y = x*exp(x)
    parma: x>0
    """
    y=np.log(x)
    x1=1e-4
    x2=x
    while abs(x1-x2)>1e-8:
        x=(x1+x2)/2
        if (np.log(x1)+x1-y)*(np.log(x)+x-y)<=0:
            x2=x
        else:
            x1=x
    return x
```

However, the two functions give different results, and the result of the function using numba  is wrong.

I have tried many examples and found that  numba's functions always get wrong results. As numba is difficult to debug, I can't find out what the problem is, can anyone give a hint?

Comment: the same. If problem, add your used x and lines related to both function calls that get different results.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it seems that two functions return the same result. For example, this code return `True` with different ranges of values:

```py
print(
    all(
        [
            lambert_jit(x) == lambert_without_jit(x) for x in np.linspace(0.5, 1e6, 10000)
        ]
    )
)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: However, in my computer, the output of your code is False.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following program:

```
print(
all(
    [
        lambert_jit(x) == lambert_without_jit(x) for x in np.linspace(0.5, 1e6, 10000)
    ]
))
```

and

```
print(
any(
    [
        lambert_jit(x) == lambert_without_jit(x) for x in np.linspace(0.5, 1e6, 10000)
    ]
))
```

The result are all False.
[image]

Comment: it is not an answer that you write here as an answer. As I mentioned, the two answers are the same. JUST test the code in a new python file that contains **only** the code from [the question that you post here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76192716/13394817) (not any other additional codes which may be the cause of this error or inequality) and after that, copy the codes to test equality as the codes in this answer. Test that. If wrong again, just ***comment*** the line *@jit(nopython=True)* and test the equality to see if you didn't make any other mistake.

Comment: I verified as you said and the results are still different. I guess it's a problem with the numba library, probably related to the machine hardware.

Comment: Do you get different results even when you commented the line *@jit(nopython=True)* above the function *lambert_jit(x)*?

Comment: After commenting,  the result is the same